# How to sort a stacked numpy array without having the other values go out of order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have the following code which contains several numpy arrays that I am trying to sort into numerical order according to ID:

```
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np
from math import log10

cat_fil = '/home/myname/filtered_catalogue.csv'
cat_fil = Table.read(cat_fil, format="ascii")

ID = np.array(cat_fil['id'])
ID = ID.astype(str)

redshift = np.array(cat_fil['z'])
redshift = redshift.astype(float)

radius = np.array(cat_fil['radius_pixels']) 
radius = radius.astype(float)

mag = np.array(cat_fil['magntiude'])
mag = mag.astype(float)


stacked = np.column_stack((ID, redshift, radius, mag))
stacked = stacked.astype(float)

idx = ((stacked[:, 1] > 0.0) & 
      (stacked[:, 2] > 10.0) &
       (stacked[:, 3] > 0.0)) 

filtered = stacked[idx]
**filtered = np.sort(filtered, axis = 0)**

print(filtered[0])
```

The problem I'm having is with sorting the array. Whenever I sort the ID in order of increasing number it does not move the rest of the other data with it, meaning that when my code runs it assigns the wrong values to each ID. Is there a way to sort all of the numpy arrays in terms of increasing numerical ID whist also keeping the actual rows together such that the correct data stays next to each other.

Comment: Does this help? https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sort-the-rows-of-a-numpy-array-by-a-column-in-python Not sure if it works with stacked arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I gather from a quick read of your question/code that you have a 2d array, which you want to sort on the first column.  Let's make a simple array like that:

```
In [258]: arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,3))                                                  
In [259]: arr                                                                                  
Out[259]: 
array([[0, 9, 7],
       [8, 7, 1],
       [3, 7, 8],
       [3, 5, 9]])
```

Sort, with the axis parameter 0, sorts each column independently:

```
In [260]: np.sort(arr, axis=0)                                                                 
Out[260]: 
array([[0, 5, 1],
       [3, 7, 7],
       [3, 7, 8],
       [8, 9, 9]])
```

But with `argsort` we get indices for sorting just the first column:

```
In [261]: idx = np.argsort(arr[:,0])                                                           
In [262]: idx                                                                                  
Out[262]: array([0, 2, 3, 1])
```

which we can then use to reorder all the rows

```
In [263]: arr[idx,:]                                                                           
Out[263]: 
array([[0, 9, 7],
       [3, 7, 8],
       [3, 5, 9],
       [8, 7, 1]])
```